# Complex calculus function have to solve in javascript in web page of html

Tags: javascript, math

This is the [image: function],  i want to solve in javascript.please help me.
Here I will give voltage(v0) as input and time increase by one from 1 to 10.I have to find u(velocity) OR straightly  i hv to get distance(integral of velocity ).

Comment: Are you asking for both Answer to calculus portion of Question and solving the calculus using `javascript`? What have you tried to solve the Question?

Comment: hi, I want to solve this equation.I want to find u(velocity).

Comment: Yes, what have you tried to solve the calculus?

Comment: Have you considered asking  Question at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ? Though, still include what you have tried to solve Question within body of Question.

Comment: I tried numeric.js.I couldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Try performing the calculus by hand before using a computer program to do so. How can you verify that the answer returned by the program is correct?

Comment: I am  doing a simulator.i have to check with program and hand.is there any way to do in programming?

Comment: See [number.js](https://github.com/numbers/numbers.js) , [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) , [Math libraries](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Math-libraries)

Comment: You want to solve a differential equation (system) `U'=u, a=b*t/U+c*u'`. You will need a numerical integrator and two initial conditions.

Comment: @LutzL i didn't get it.can you tell it briefly?pls

Comment: Try to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830807/runge-kutta-problems-in-js if you want to integrate yourself. Please document your attempts of using `numeric.js` (by editing the question), the examples in http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html section "Solving ODEs" seem rather straightforward.